# how to print the contents of a 2 dimensional array to a text box in a table like format?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, output

I need to print the contents of my 2 dimensional array to a textbox called txtExecute in a table like format just like the one below:

```
        Mon    Tue    Wed    Thu    Fri
Week 1  1      2      3      4      5
Week 2  6      7      8      9      10
Week 3  11     12     13     14     15
Week 4  16     17     18     19     20
```

I have got the format of the weeks and days right but I can't figure out how to get the arrays values exactly like that. Here is my code so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int[,] productsArray = new int[4, 5];

    private void AddValuesToArray() 
    {
        txtExecute.Text = "Filling the array with user input..." + "\r\n\r\n";

        String value;
        int num;

        for (int week = 0; week < productsArray.GetLength(0); week++)
        {
            for (int day = 0; day < productsArray.GetLength(1); day++)
            {
                value = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter value for " + day + " of week " + week, "Enter Value");
                try
                {
                    while (!(int.TryParse(value, out num)))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Not a valid number, try again.");
                        value = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter a number", "Enter Number");

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Value entered is not in a valid format");
                }

                productsArray[week, day] += int.Parse(value);
            }               
        }
        txtExecute.Text += "The product allocation is as follows:" + "\r\n\r\n";
    }

    private void ArrayFormat()
    {
        txtExecute.Text += "\t" + "Mon" + "\t" + "Tue" + "\t" + "Wed" + "\t" + "Thu" + "\t" + "Fri" + "\r\n";
         for(int week = 0; week < productsArray.GetLength(0); week++)
         {
             txtExecute.Text += "Week " + week + "\t" +"\r\n";
             for (int day = 0; day < productsArray.GetLength(0); day++)
             {
                 txtExecute.Text += productsArray[0, 0];
             }
         }

    }

    private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddValuesToArray();
        ArrayFormat();
    }
 }
```

}

And here is the output I am getting:

```
        Mon    Tue    Wed    Thu    Fri
Week 0  
1111Week 1  
1111Week 2  
1111Week 3  
1111
```

I realise I am only outputting 1 element, and I will have to print out the rest but I want to solve this problem first.

Comment: I strongly recommend using a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this. Otherwise, your best bet is to use a monospaced font and use spaces to line things up. (If you try to use tabs, you'll be in a world of pain...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, your `ArrayFormat()` function should be like this ...

```
private void ArrayFormat()
{
    txtExecute.Text += "\t" + "Mon" + "\t" + "Tue" + "\t" + "Wed" + "\t" + "Thu" + "\t" + "Fri" + "\r\n";
     for(int week = 0; week < productsArray.GetLength(0); week++)
     {
         txtExecute.Text += "Week " + week + "\t";
         for (int day = 0; day < productsArray.GetLength(0); day++)
         {
             txtExecute.Text += productsArray[week, day] + "\t";
         }
         txtExecute.Text += "\r\n";
     }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
txtExecute.Text += "\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\r\n";
```

is shorter

**EDIT:**

```
txtExecute.Text += "Week " + (week+1) + "\t";
```

to start from `Week 1`

Comment: I bet the tabs won't line things up properly when then numbers get bigger.

Comment: @MatthewWatson ah, yes, sure, i agree with you, but OP just wants day values to be printed which are less then 32... and OP might be still need to skip 2 day values for **Sun** and **Sat** and day 1 might be started from **Tue** or **Wed** :)

Comment: Fair enough - It might work! I've always had endless trouble trying to use tabs with proportional fonts to line things up.

Comment: Yeah the number wont go above 20, so I'm not worried about big numbers. This works almost perfectly but for some reason the Friday column is blank, do you have any idea why this is? Also I know this wasn't really part of the question but do you know how I can get it to say week 1 week 2 week 3 week 4 instead of week 0 week 1 week 2 week 3?

Comment: change this line `txtExecute.Text += "Week " + week + "\t";` to `txtExecute.Text += "Week " + (week+1) + "\t";` and you will bet week 1 week 2 week 3 week 4

Answer (score 1):

You're always outputting the same array element.

```
for (int day = 0; day < productsArray.GetLength(0); day++)
{
     txtExecute.Text += productsArray[week, day];
}
```

This will solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your tabs with spaces and use `String.PadRight` in ArrayFormat method.
And adding array members with `productsArray[0, 0]` doesn't help you, either. Replace it with `productsArray[week, day];`